# I got a question on whether the function is one-one or many-one and onto or into .

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The question is:
Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $f(x)= \frac{x-m}{x-n}$ where $m \not = n$.

1) is it one-one or many-one

2) is it into or onto

I tried and I think my answer is one one and into but I don't think I followed the right steps to . if someone could show me how to solve the 1st part with concept of differentiability ( strictly increasing or strictly decreasing) and also the second part. I couldn't find the solution to this on the web so here I am.
Thanks .

Comment: For (2) look if you can get the value $1$. For (1), if you want to take derivatives, you can do so. $f'(x)=\frac{m-n}{(x-n)^2}$, which has a constant sign equal to that of $m-n$.

Comment: How is $f(n)$ defined?

Comment: @almagest question didn't include anything other than what I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

HINT (for $f(x)=\frac{x-m}{x-n}$)

$$
\frac{x-m}{x-n}=\frac{x-n+n-m}{x-n}=1+\frac{n-m}{x-n}.
$$
Can you see the shape of the graph of it now?

Comment: Sorry no, I am not that good with graphs and this also

Comment: @osmanmalik Have you ever been taught about homographic function (its graph is a hyperbola)?

Comment: No never I am 17 years old studying in high school. I only know basics about hyperbola like it's standard equation is x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 1 .

Comment: @osmanmalik So please look at a graph near the end of this: https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funkcja_homograficzna (in Polish, but in English version is not present). As it have a horizontal asymptote, it is not (in this case) onto.  Can you see that it is one-to-one?

Comment: Yes. I now understand fully. Sincerely thanks for showing this to me

Answer (score 0):

(a) f is one-to-one (injective) if f maps every element of A to a unique element in B. In other words **no element of B are mapped to by two or more elements of A** ,mathematically saying if  $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})\implies x_{1}=x_{2}$

if $\dfrac{x_{1}-m}{x_{1}-n}=\dfrac{x_{2}-m}{x_{2}-n}$

$x_{1}(m-n)=x_{2}(m-n)$

$(x_{1}-x_{2})(m-n)=0$ and $m\neq n$

so, $x_{1}=x_{2}$

so **this function is one one** as you found yourself

(b)f is onto (surjective)if every element of B is mapped to by some element of A. In other words, nothing is left out.

$y=\dfrac{x-m}{x-n}\implies$
$x=\dfrac{ny-m}{y-1}$

corresponding to  $y=f(x)=1$ there is no $x$ present in it's domain so **function is not surjective.**